# Mongoose skip and limit. Generate limit dynamically provides infinite data

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, intersection-observer, react-infinite-scroll-component

I have the problem that when I have reached the end of my data, Mongoose continues to provide me with data.If I constantly set the limit to 11, everything works. But I want to create the limit dynamically.

```
export async function POST(request) {
const body = await request.json();

try {
  mongoConection();
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
}

const products = await Product.find({})
 .sort({
  createdAt: -1,
 })
.skip(body.skip)
.limit(body.limit);

 return NextResponse.json({ products });
}
```

MainImage.js

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const fetchProducts = async () => {
setLoadMore(true);

const fetching = await FetchInitProducts(
  page,
  sessionStorage.getItem("currentLimit")
    ? sessionStorage.getItem("currentLimit")
    : 11
);

useEffect(() => {
 fetchProducts();
}, [page]);

 <SingleImage isLast={index === result.length - 1} newLimit={() => {
  setPage(page + 11);sessionStorage.setItem("currentLimit", page + 11);}}
  product={product} handleClickOnImageEvent={handleClickOnImageEvent}/>
```

SingleImage.js:

```
export default function SingleImage({
   handleClickOnImageEvent,
   product,
   newLimit,
   isLast,
  }) {

  useEffect(() => {
  if (!productRef?.current) return;

 const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (isLast && entry.isIntersecting) {
    newLimit();
    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
   }
 });

  observer.observe(productRef.current);
}, [isLast]);

   ...
}
```